# Improve popup jquery code to meet market standard

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm creating a template, now my search & navigation opens in a full screen popup when someone clicks the icon. I have setup two icons for this. & to handle the click request I've written the below code:

```
  $(".demo-menu > a").on("click", function(){
    $(this).parent().addClass('demo-show-menu');
  });
  $(".demo-menu-close").on("click", function(){
    $('.demo-menu-close').closest('.demo-menu ').removeClass('demo-show-menu');
  }); 

  $(".demo-search > a").on("click", function(){
    $(this).parent().addClass('demo-show-search');
  });
  $(".demo-search-close").on("click", function(){
    $('.demo-search-close').closest('.demo-search ').removeClass('demo-show-search');
  });
```

I'm still in learning stage of javascript. But I can understand that since both piece of codes for the icons are same, I can combine them in one to make the code look professional. Can someone tell me how can I achieve this?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it’s a request for a code review and should be posted to the code review site

Comment: What you need to read is jQuery's [Multiple selectors](https://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/) section. Your code should look like `$(".demo-menu > a, .demo-search > a")` (comma separated selectors).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can export the adding of listeners to a method.

```
function addOnClickListeners(popup_type) {
    $(".demo-" + popup_type + " > a").on("click", function(){
        $(this).parent().addClass('demo-show-' + popup_type);
    });
    $(".demo-" + popup_type + "-close").on("click", function(){
      $('.demo-' + popup_type + '-close').closest('.demo-' + popup_type + ' ').removeClass('demo-show-' + popup_type);
    });
}
```

*Notice: I replaced 'menu' with the method parameter `popup_type`.*
You would then call the method with different parameters to register the listeners to different popups.

```
addOnClickListeners("menu");
addOnClickListeners("search");
```

Comment: Thanks... I like how much clean it is. I totally understand what is going on by just looking at the code. I need to do more practice to write like this.